# curl "Unknown error" when using Net::Curl::Easy and "pushopt" options

Tags: perl, curl

I need to pass authorization data to the proxy. However, this code (see below) results in an error.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$| = 1;

use Net::Curl::Easy qw(:constants);
 
my $easy = Net::Curl::Easy->new();
$easy->setopt( CURLOPT_URL, "https://checkip.amazonaws.com/" );
$easy->setopt( CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );
$easy->setopt( CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_VERIFYPEER , 0 );
$easy->setopt(CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$easy->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$easy->setopt(CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl");
$easy->setopt(CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://35.244.25.186:3128"); # some proxy
$easy->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$easy->pushopt(CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER, ['username: apikey']); # when set "HTTPHEADER", everything is work fine

$easy->perform();
```

Tried to change proxyheader to httpheader, no errors. But, the header is sent to both the proxy and the target server, which does not suit me, since it is necessary that the header be sent only to the proxy.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. Python code that works similarly does not cause errors.

```
import sys
import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://checkip.amazonaws.com/')
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, 1)
c.setopt(c.PROXY_SSL_VERIFYPEER , 0)
c.setopt(c.PROXY_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, "curl")
c.setopt(c.PROXY, "http://35.244.25.186:3128")
c.setopt(c.PROXYHEADER, ['a: b'])
c.perform()
```

Comment: *"However, this code (see below) results in an error."* - please provide the actual details of the error. It might just be that you set the wrong header or provided the wrong API key. Do you have any actual specification of how the header should look like?

Comment: The same python code does not give any errors. Checked. When trying to send arbitrary headers to the proxy, an error occurred.

Comment: I don't see why `pushopt` is used here. Use `setopt` since you didn't set anything to push onto.

Comment: Using ```setopt``` results in a segmentation fault

Comment: *"The same python code"* - please provide the code to ensure that it actually does the same. *"an error occurred"* - again, do provide the actual error details and not only the information that something unspecific went wrong.

Comment: I added the python code in my question, since it's inconvenient to format it here. Regarding the error, the perl script above just gives such an error "unknown error" and that's it...

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a bug to me in Net::Curl. `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`  and `CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER` should be treated both as a list. But `CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER` wasn't specifically treated, so it likely was used as an integer argument only which broke `pushopt` (since no list) and caused a segmentation fault with `setopt` (since a list was treated as an integer).

Patch for fixing the issue can be found on the bug report recently opened (likely by the OP): https://github.com/sparky/perl-Net-Curl/issues/73#issuecomment-1588512766:

```
--- a/Curl_Easy.xsh
+++ b/Curl_Easy.xsh
@@ -29,6 +29,7 @@ typedef enum {
 
 static const CURLoption perl_curl_easy_option_slist[] = {
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
+       CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER,
        CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES,
 #ifdef CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT
        CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT,
```

Comment: (The maintainer plans to release the fix later this week.)